# SQL Query to Obtain the Oldest People

Tags: sql, sql-server, max, aggregate-functions

I am trying to find the oldest customers in my database. I want just their full names and their ages, but my current results are outputting all customers and their ages (not just the oldest). What am I doing wrong here?

```
SELECT 
        LTRIM(CONCAT(' ' + Prefix, ' ' + FirstName, 
        ' ' + MiddleName, ' ' + LastName, ', ' + Suffix)),
        MAX(DATEDIFF(year, BirthDate, GETDATE()))
    FROM
        Customers
    WHERE 
        BirthDate is not null
    GROUP BY
        Prefix, FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, Suffix
    ORDER BY
        MAX(DATEDIFF(year, e.BirthDate, GETDATE())) desc
```

Note that there seems to be multiple customers with the same oldest age.

Comment: Could you please provide sample data and required result. I guess, GROUP BY should look like GROUP BY LTRIM(CONCAT(' ' + Prefix, ' ' + FirstName, 
        ' ' + MiddleName, ' ' + LastName, ', ' + Suffix))

Comment: Consider using `TOP(n)` or `TOP(n) PERCENT` to limit your result set. [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/top-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Google the having clause.

Comment: Define "oldest" - unless you have more than one person with the same birthdate, there's only going to be a single person. Are you just wanting to list the top few n in age order?

Comment: if you want to restrict your result to some condition, then you need to also provide that condition. The only condition in your query is that birthdate may not be null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not defined what you mean with "oldest customers".
So I will give a few options you could try

to see a list of customers with the oldest on top, use a simple querie like this

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, Suffix, BirthDate
FROM   Customers
WHERE  BirthDate is not null
ORDER BY BirthDate desc
```

to restrict the result to a number of rows, for example the 10 oldest, use `top 10`

```
SELECT top 10
       FirstName, LastName, Suffix, BirthDate
FROM   Customers
WHERE  BirthDate is not null
ORDER BY BirthDate desc
```

to restrict the result to all customers born after a certain date, add to the where clause

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, Suffix, BirthDate
FROM   Customers
WHERE  BirthDate is not null
and    BirtDate < '19920101'
ORDER BY BirthDate desc
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to do before you do anything else is define a unique numeric primary key on the Customers table.

```
ALTER TABLE Customers ADD Cust_Id int IDENTITY(1,1);
ALTER TABLE Customers ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Customers PRIMARY KEY (Cust_Id);
```

After you've doe that, the following code will give you the "oldest customer (or customers) in your database".

```
With qry1 As (
    SELECT      Cust_Id, 
                DATEDIFF(year, BirthDate, GETDATE()) As Age
    FROM        Customers 
    WHERE       BirthDate is not null 
),
qry2 As (
    SELECT      Max(Age) As Max_Age
    FROM        qry1
)
SELECT      Customers.Cust_Id,
            Customers.Prefix,
            Customers.FirstName,
            Customers.MiddleName,
            Customers.LastName,
            Customers.Suffix,
            Qry1.Age
FROM        Customers
Inner Join  Qry1 On Customers.Cust_Id = Qry1.Cust_Id
Inner Join  Qry2 On Qry1.Age = Qry2.Max_Age
```